# Intuition with probabilities of tossing coins

Tags: probability

Say I flipped $10$ unfair coins (with probabilities of tails $51\%$ and heads $49\%$). I want to know the probability of having at least $M$ tails given that there were at least $M$ identical results.

I need your help explaining the results.

After I done the calculations I used different $M$ values and watched the results, I have noticed that for numbers smaller than $5$ the probability is very high (with around $99\%$ when $M=1$ and $64\%$ when $M=5$)
and then when $M=6$ the probability drops to around $53\%$ and slowly going up until $M=10$ with around $59\%$

This result is very confusing for me since when $M$ is $1$ its almost $100\%$ then it decreases and then $M=6$ is the minimum and then slowly increasing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuition is that if $M$ is less than $6$ then you can have both $M$ heads and $M$ tails, and for $M$ very small you almost certainly do.

For $M\geq 6$, you know that you either have $M$ tails or $M$ heads, but not both. Since tails are more likely than heads, the probability of having $M$ tails will be a bit more than $50\%$ for $M=6$. As you increase $M$, the number of extra coins of the more common type will increase, and the fact that tails are individually more likely will have a greater effect.

Suppose you instead plotted the probability of **not** having $M$ heads, given there are at least $M$ of the same type. This will look much more like you expect -- it just increases. The key point is that the two probabilities are equal for $M\geq 6$, but different for $M\leq 5$ (because you can have $M$ of both).

Comment: Ok I think I am starting to see this. I understand why for M≥6 the probability increasing but then why when M≤5 the probability decreasing ?

Comment: Because if $M\leq 5$ the conditional doesn't do anything (either heads or tails *must* have at least $M$). So you are just calculating the simple probability of having at least $M$ tails, which is less likely as $M$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

With no condition, you expect the most likely number of tails to be $5$ and for it to decay in both directions, since $p$ is quite close to $1/2$. The condition does nothing for $M \leq 5$, but it changes things a bit for $M>5$. For example with $M=6$ you remove the case of $5$ tails; with $M=7$ you remove the case of $4$, $5$ or $6$ tails; etc. This makes the chances of having $M$ tails or more more likely because it removes the "middle" possibilities, i.e. the possibilities $x$ with $x$ and $10-x$ both less than $M$.

Comment: Thanks Ian but I still can't understand why M=6 is the minimum probability to happen but M=10 have higher probability and M=1-5 have even higher probability

Comment: @Jynxed Ultimately it just boils down to the calculation going that way; the situation is sensitive to both it being $n=10$ and $p=0.51$. Just at an intuitive level, the numerator (the probability of the number of tails being in $[M,10]$) drops with $M$, but the denominator (the probability of the number of tails being in $[0,10-M] \cup [M,10]$) also drops with $M$ once $M$ goes past $5$. The competition of these two effects creates results like those you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite interesting.

I do the calculations and get the same results.

[image]

For each $M$, the conditional probability is the sum of the numbers in green cells divided by the sum of the numbers in coloured cells.

It is not strange that for smaller $M$, the conditional probability is nearly $1$, as most coloured cells are coloured green. For $M\ge 6$, the number of green cells and the number of yellow cells are the same. The conditional probability is close to $0.5$. It is slightly larger than $0.5$ since the coin is biased.

---

Remark:

The following table shows the calculation when the coin is not biased.

[image]

Comment: The more I think of it the more I see I should "give up" to the math.. I understand why based on the calculations we get this results but can't seem to accept this results as logical ones